# UDP Broadcast over multiple subnets

Tags: networking, udp, broadcast

I'm working on a small local network chat/filesharing application that periodically sends out a UDP broadcast telling all the other clients on the network of it's name and online status.
On the majority of networks, it works perfectly; however when attempting this at my University's campus, it fails.

I'm not exactly sure why, but I think it's because the clients are connected to the same backbone but on different routers (repeaters).

Is there a way for UDP broadcast to 'reach' other routers on the same network backbone?

Comment: Simple answer: no, you're reaching everything in the same http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_domain . It might be possible for the administrators to configure routers to repeat broadcasts, but from a user point of view I don't think there's a general way to request it to happen.